# When is it acceptable to use features from a later minor version update of python in a setup.py script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, setuptools, f-string

## Original question title:

**Should we use python 3.6 features in setup.py?**

I've created a setup.py for a private library installer which depends on python 3.6.  I attempted to make the file a little more friendly for anyone trying to install it on python versions prior and realized I had a major flaw in my thinking.

**I'm using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) in the setup.py which *only work in >=3.6*!**

Anyone trying to run the setup.py in a previous version of python won't even get to the first line of code which checks the interpreter version. So this got me thinking about guidelines for creating a setup.py file and what other syntactical limitations might exist which would prevent setup.py from running properly in multiple environments.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
PIP Install script for XXXXXX packages
"""
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3,6):
    sys.exit('Sorry, Python < 3.6 is not supported')

from setuptools import setup

NAME = 'abcutil'
AUTHOR = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

CLASSIFIERS = """\
Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
Intended Audience :: Developers
Programming Language :: Python
Programming Language :: Python :: 3
Topic :: Software Development
Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows
Operating System :: Unix
Operating System :: MacOS
"""

MAJOR               = 1
MINOR               = 1
MICRO               = 0
ISRELEASED          = False
VERSION             = f'{MAJOR}.{MINOR}.{MICRO}'

setup(name = NAME,
      maintainer = AUTHOR,
      version=VERSION,
      maintainer_email = 'XXXXXXX',
      description='XXXXXXX utility packages',
      author = AUTHOR,
      download_url = 'https://gitlabXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX',
      license = 'BSD',
      classifiers=[_f for _f in CLASSIFIERS.split('\n') if _f],
      python_requires=">=3.6",
      packages=[NAME, f"{NAME}.selenium", f"{NAME}.regression_helpers"],
      install_requires = ['selenium==3.9', 'requests>=2.18.4', 'python-dateutil', 'pytz'],
      dependency_links=['']
      )
```

Running the above will give you this:

```
$ python setup.py
  File "setup.py", line 30
    VERSION             = f'{MAJOR}.{MINOR}.{MICRO}'
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## My question is

What is recommended for setup.py when it comes using interpreter features limited to newer versions?

---

**Edit:**

3.8.2 is out now and it got me thinking about this question again. So I've re-worded the question.

**When is it acceptable to use features from a later minor version update of python in a setup.py script?**

F-strings were added in 3.6. At what point does it become acceptable to start using them in the setup.py? Two minor versions? Three? The next major version?

Comment: Your setup.py declares `python_requires=">=3.6"`, so basically your library won't be installed on python<3.6. If somebody with Python 3.5 try to install your package, it will fail anyway.

Comment: And replacing f-strings is easy. Ex: `f'{MAJOR}.{MINOR}.{MICRO}'` becomes `'{MAJOR}.{MINOR}.{MICRO}'.format(MAJOR=MAJOR, MINOR=MINOR, MICRO=MICRO)` or simpler: `'{}.{}.{}'.format(MAJOR, MINOR, MICRO)`

Comment: Keep it simple. Use `format`. Most literal constructs have a counterpart in the form of a function/method.

Comment: @Antwane users trying to install this on 3.5 won't even get to the point where setuptools checks the version.

Comment: Distribute wheels instead of source dists. This way, your setup script will be executed only once - in your working environment when building the wheel file and where you have the full control over the interpreter version used. Leave the source dists for power users, in that case the version info check on the top of the setup script is enough.

Comment: We are using a private git repo thus source dists.  I'll look into building wheels, but tbh it seemed like more work than I was willing to endure.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't it simply the same rule as always: use the features available to the Python interpreters that you are targeting? As @hoefling said, the one exception I could envision is if you publish  _built distributions_ (most likely _wheel_), then you can get away with some newer features in `setup.py` since (as far as I know) that file doesn't appear in the built distributions.

Comment: I agree.  Setting the version in the setup.py in this case would solve that problem.  Except when it didn't. TBH, this might only be an issue with 3.6 and f-strings.  I couldn't think of another good example where new features in a release would break setuptools so much that it wouldn't tell the user they can't use that package.   The whole point of setup.py is to help the user and possibly prevent them from using a package that is incompatible.  Which raises interesting questions about what features should be used _inside_ the setup.py script.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the following: "_Which raises interesting questions about what features should be used inside the setup.py script_"? Unless I am missing something, there is no mystery here: **use the features available to the Python interpreters that you are targeting**. If the `setup.py` script has to run on Python X.Y, then use things that work on that interpreter, no way around it.

Comment: I get that, I do.  Prior to now I've always been able to at least run setup.py to the point where it informs me that I cannot use said package because I don't have xzy version.  We sort of depend on the reliability of setup.py to work no matter what.  In the case of my example above, using a new feature would break that reliability.  This would suggest that how we build setup.py and the features utilized therein should be as compatible as possible.  (i.e. trying to run setup.py for a 3.x package in 2.x)

Comment: I don't understand what is expected from this question, so I will vote to close it, feel free to make clarifications. There is already a `if sys.version_info < (3,6):` to stop the script when running with an earlier Python version and `python_requires=">=3.6"` as well, isn't it enough?

Comment: Putting a version check is fine. My question asks 'what is recommended'.  Is my current solution fine? does it go against community/industry norms of packaging?  I'm not specifically trying to fix my code.  I'm trying to get a sense of what should go into setup.py and what should be avoided.  The setuptools documentation doesn't really go into _this_ kind of thing (presumably because it's not really come up before).

Comment: "_What is recommended_" is that it should work. Only you know what Python versions you want to support. One way to choose would be to go with all the [versions that haven't reached _end of life_ yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Table_of_versions), which as of today should be _3.5_, _3.6_, _3.7_, _3.8_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's wrap up an important discussion covered in the comments: your `setup.py` containing an f-string won't be invoked anyway, unless the client's pip version is extremely old. Older than introduction of support for `python_requires` metadata, which was in pip 9.0.0 (2016) [(changelog)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v9-0-0). Note that [all direct invocations of `setup.py` are effectively deprecated](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html), and if `pip` was able to find a wheel distribution then there will be no `setup.py` executed at all, that file is not even included in the wheel.

Now to answer the actual question: it's acceptable to use newer language features anytime, even *immediately*, as long as your package metadata communicates the minimum required Python version which is supported.

You're already doing this in the example code in the question by providing a lower bound on the [`python_requires`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires):

```
setup(
    ...
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    ...
)
```

The built distribution will have metadata associated advertising that a Python version of at least 3.6 is required, which means Python runtimes older than 3.6 will not attempt to install the package in the first place. In fact, `pip` will not even attempt to *download* it in that case.

The Python version requirement will be displayed on the [project landing page](https://test.pypi.org/project/abcutil/) like this:

[image: python requires render]

And the actual release file, [abcutil-1.1.0.tar.gz](https://test.pypi.org/project/abcutil/#files), will be "invisible" to lower Python versions for all practical purposes, for example:

```
$ python2 -m pip install --index-url=https://test.pypi.org/simple abcutil
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement abcutil (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for abcutil
```

You may enable pip's verbose logging to witness the package finder seeing and intentionally skipping this distribution:

```
$ python2 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple abcutil -v |& grep abcutil-1
  Link requires a different Python (2.7.18 not in: u'>=3.6'): https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/8a/45a45b35deae088b184b776fb11392e13023ee566d8ff9484dba49a310cc/abcutil-1.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=72aeec98ff91fadaf49eea1f0c3fd9fa45dfb304bbbf4e0b79a04fcbcd76072f (from https://test.pypi.org/simple/abcutil/) (requires-python:>=3.6)
```

Comment: _"your setup.py containing an f-string won't be invoked"_ Is that true even for developer installations?  `pip install -e /mypackage`  It's been a while, but when this question was originally asked, it was invoking the setup.py.

Comment: Ahh.  You point out something I hadn't even considered: which is packages on pypi have versioning logic that handles this problem in the majority of cases.  /smacks_forehead _of course!_  The version f-string is a non-issue had that package been uploaded to pypi.  This really isn't much of a problem now that I look at it that way.  It's likely ONLY an issue for those packages that are dev installed.

Comment: It's not true in that case of a development install, because then you are dealing with a local directory and not a package index, so the package metadata is not available. But the failure mode in this case (a SyntaxError) will be loud and clear, obvious to a developer, so I wouldn't worry too much about that.